# What are the pros and cons of adding a second ground rod at the "Alt Power" location In this diagram?

Tags: electrical, generator, transfer-switch

My question is whether or not I should add a second ground rod at the generator location? This is shown as the "Alt Power Source (2024)" box in this diagram.

Please recognize that this diagram is far from complete and has some inaccurate detail but it should show sufficient detail for answering the question.  The utility company has already powered this up, and I can see pros and cons for grounding this system either way.

There is a ground rod on the line segment between `Utility Line Power` and `Meter Socket`. However, that neutral/ground coming into the meter socket becomes shared at S1. So, both transmission lines are grounded at the `Source` if you're looking at utility power as the only source; but both sources have dedicated lines even though they're on opposites sides of the dual transmission line. Looking from the alternate power side, those two separate dedicated lines are grounded, but only at the far end of those transmission lines and not at that source. Even though each transmission line shares this common neutral/ground at the utility end, the dual transmission lines are only grounded at one end.

If I ground the alternate power source, I'm grounding both transmission lines at that end and effectively tying both ends of the transmission line down. This would be called ground-looping; but we are talking about a distance of about 275 ft, and this is not a sound system application. It's a power application.

- Do I benefit by tying both ends of this dual transmission line to ground?
- Will that effectively reduce voltage drop on these lines, or does it not matter at all?

  - I've heard answers both ways and I'm still not satisfied that I've found a definitive answer.

The generator at the box labeled "Alt Power Source (2024) has yet to be installed but everything else, with the exception of a few housekeeping details is done.

Yes, there is a generator port available on the rack where S1 is located.  It's a temporary 240V 30A port. The primary port at the Milk Shed will be a 240V 50A port. Obviously, the generators can't be both run at the same time in this arrangement, but since I'm going to be the only one hooking them up, that's not going to be an issue. The bare bones 30A port was a temporary port I hurriedly put in last fall to get us through this winter before I could install the permanent 50A port at the milk shed where I have secure space to store a larger generator, but I don't think my lines will support a whole house generator. That's extraneous detail but it might help to understand why we went this way.  Because of the added refrigeration equipment I'll be installing in the milk shed soon to support vertical integration in running a small family start-up beef cattle business, that node really does need 100A service, and that node has to have full emergency power backup. We had to go to a 320A continuous service at the meter socket with new lines to the milk shed to make this work.

The question remains:  Should I ground both ends of those lines or not?

[image: Dual Dedicated Transmission Lines for Switching Power (Load-Shedding) at Both House and Milk Shed]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do your backup generators have a floating neutral or a bonded neutral?  (If you can't tell, post make/model info and we can try to dig it up

Comment: Also, what size are the conduits for the various feeds involved (between the two power racks, as well as from the switches to the house and shed, and the nipple from the meter socket to the switch for the house?)

Comment: Most of that information is on the drawing.  Some detail is omitted.  The line from S1 to the house is all 4/0 x3.   The interconnects between S1 and the 400A circuit breaker are all 4/0 x3, as are the interconnects between S2 and the milk shed's distribution panel.  I don't know anything about our existing generator.  It's a Harbor Freight 7.5kW peak model and the manual is gone.  The manual said to ground the generator and has a wimpy little terminal to do it with.  We always do. Our future generator will be a  DuroMax XP15000E.  Milk Shed:  RecVeh 50A, Cold Room 30A, plus lights & outlets.

Comment: I need the size of the conduits the wires are in (unless they're all direct burial, which just needs to be mentioned if that's the case).

Comment: We tested running the house freezers, lights & WiFi with the existing 30A generator last fall and it worked fine.  Right now, the cold room in the milk shed is under construction.  From manufacturer's drawings, with all components on at the same time, it shouldn't draw more than 25A & the compressor uses a 50Hz/60Hz  inverter.   The 50A RV outlet at the milk shed is for the grandparent's visits.  We haven't used that port yet.  I'm putting the final line between S2 and the 50A port in right now.  It's planned to be 6 AWG. Could still run 1/0 x3 between S2 and 50A port but seems like overkill.

Comment: The conduit sizes matter here because this setup may need more invasive rework than simply adding a ground rod (right now, it violates Code in a rather nasty way, and adding more ground rods is liable to make things worse for both you and your bovine buddies on the ranch)

Comment: Both cable runs are direct burial into a single 24" to 36" trench.  Depth of trench varies because this is Arkansas and working in the ground here is a nightmare.  Each of the 1/0 x3 cable sets come out of the ground into separate 4" PVC 90 degree elbows at both ends.  After the elbows, there's some short 2" flex into the electrical boxes.

Comment: Oh, and this is actually Nassau National Cable "Quad" Notre Dame cable so there is a separate 2 AWG ground wire that's insulated that's part of each set.  Ground and Neutral are bonded at S1.  But here's the cool thing.  Ground and neutral are not bonded at the Service Masthead.  They have separate discharge paths.  I forced this so they would have to do it this way.

Comment: That's helpful at least!  Mind describing where else neutral and ground are bonded in the system, and if the meter + S1 combo are at the house or remote from it?

Comment: I have a 3" PVC service mast, but it is C-clamped in place a steel support post that's the regulation 14" height here.  The neutral comes off the transformer and bonds to the top of that support post, making it the first and quickest real ground path.  This makes the entire steel mast support and rack a path to ground that is more direct than the route created by the neutral inside the service mast to S1 to the ground rod.  In other words, my true ground line does not share the inside of the service mast with the other cabling.  It runs on the outside surface of the steel support.

Comment: The meter and S1 are about 75 ft away from the house.  They share the same POS rack.  That rack is right underneath the utility's power pole that service's our house.

Comment: I've added photos of this so you can see what it is I'm trying to describe.  Please don't laugh at my conduit routing methods.  It's what made it work.  For a number of reasons, I couldn't get a pair of cables to line right up with the bottoms of the boxes they needed to go to.  If the boxes had prefab cabling, I wouldn't have needed to do this.

Comment: Is the box below the meter a service disconnect or merely a tapbox?

Comment: There are a few more details that bear on the decision as to whether to ground the other end of the transmission line or not.  I have never been able to find the original ground to the house system.  In this part of Arkansas, there is no county building code, no code inspectors and no code enforcement.  Entergy, the electric utility , requires that ground rods be BURIED before being connected. They required I put in a new ground rod at the rack.   The house is old and appears to have been renovated in the early 1980s.  The house electrical distribution is at capacity on a 200A service.

Comment: Putting in the POS rack at the power pole helped solve some other problems.  It is the shortest distance to the milk shed, not shown in the photos.  It made it possible to avoid running into underground lines and tree root systems surrounding the house.  In the bottom left corner of the S1 switch, you can see an aluminum plate. That's where I ground the 30A generator, but that's effectively the same ground location as the POS rack ground.  For a number of reasons, I can't use a 50A generator at the location.   It has to be run from the milk shed.

Comment: The box below the meter is where the 400A circuit breaker is located.  All the wiring from mast head to circuit breaker is 500 mcm, per utility requirement.  After the circuit breaker, the lines split.  The lines to S1 are 4/0.  The lines to the blue transmission line are 1/0.  The voltage drop calculations for 75degC showed that 1/0 would be sufficient for a 100A load given the distance and given PVC conduit, but those lines are buried and not in conduit.

Comment: One more detail:  The original Point of Service from the utility power pole was simply goofy.  It was buried service from the pole to the house with the original meter mounted outside the house on a brick wall.  What the utility company does here is to run the service lines down an open piece of conduit mounted to their poles.  This conduit does not have a service masthead.  The wiring from the transformer goes into this open conduit, down the pole and is then buried.  Again, there is no service head on their conduit and so nothing prevents rainwater from collecting inside it.

Comment: Question Restated: The original question is should the back end of this dual transmission system be grounded. The one comment that seems to control this answer is the one from ThreePhaseEel where he asks if the generator has a floating neutral or a bonded neutral. I take it that a floating neutral would be a generator wound in a "Delta" configuration and a bonded neutral would be one that is wound in a "Y" configuration. I'm not sure I know how to find that out short of taking the generator apart, which I won't do. Does anyone know how a DuroMax XP15000E is wound.

Comment: Just heard back from Duromax.  Their XP15000E is a floating neutral generator that will require a ground rod on the input side of the S2 transfer switch.  Problem solved.  Getting this answer took a lot of work, but now that I have it, I'm convinced it is the right answer.  Thank you, ThreePhaseEel, for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: The ground rod on the generator side isn't a bad idea, but it's not sufficient to rectify the issues with this system, see my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

### Your problem is bigger than what a ground rod can fix

The bad news for you is that your issue is larger than what can be fixed by driving a ground rod.  In fact, the issue of a "ground loop" has nothing to do with what can actually go wrong here.  Instead, the problem has to do with the bonded neutrals in both transfer switches creating a *parallel neutral path* that could, in the worst case, cause certain faults in the normal power system to propagate into the backup power system and render it unusable as a source of backup power.  (It's also a violation of the intent of NEC 300.3(B) and 310.10(H), as the two paths are very electrically different.)

I've marked up the picture below to show the two paths.  The normal path for neutral current from the house is shown in green, running via the feed from S1 to the house and then back to the meter/main via the normal power feed into S1.  However, some of the neutral current also takes the red path, all the way out to the shed and back.

This is a problem because the neutral wires out to the shed can't handle the full 200A the house draws.  If the neutral wire from S1 to the main breaker starts to fail under high loads on the neutral (i.e. a very imbalanced load between the two service legs), then more of that current will flow through the red path.  Once the green path fails totally, then you have up to 200A of current flowing through long wires rated only for 120A.  This will cause them to start to overheat and eventually fail as well, leaving you with a mess of open neutrals and a useless generator.

[image: system diagram scribbled on to show the neutral paths]

Fixing this will require swapping your transfer switches for 3-pole units that can switch the neutral path in addition to the hots.  Since you have a floating neutral generator, you'll also have to tuck the bonding jumper for the backup system into S2 instead of having it live at the generator.

While you're in there, you'll also want to clean up any errant neutral-ground bonds in hardware downstream of the main breaker, such as S1, and make sure that all feeders are of the four-wire type, with a separate neutral and ground.  This will prevent multiple grounding of the system from introducing stray currents into the ground, as stray currents will make your bovine buddies not so bullish on their electrically powered creature comforts.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive input.  It is well appreciated.  In the back of my mind, I have to admit I've seen the problem of having neutral paths of unequal lengths but have not known what to do about it.  As a small time rancher working in a very difficult market, due to well protected monopolistic forces, that our options have neve been very good for sustaining and growing our business.  The local market has been nonexistent since the "pandemic" Right now, we have (6) 20cuft freezers full of beef on a single 20A circuit in the house.  And one freezer failed from the freezer being too full.

Comment: We've had difficult choices to make.  Putting in a walk-in cold room in the milk shed has been our best option, but even getting parts has been hard.  We're lucky to have been able to afford and buy the tied-neutral transfer switches we have.  This  is one reason why I put in two switches, so I could do load shedding and isolate loads.  Granted, this doesn't solve the whole problem, but it's an affordable solution for us.  Right now, we're just concerned about making it through the next few seasons.  I'm actually relieved to hear that your concern deals more with the longevity of the system.

Comment: You should come out to Arkansas and set up shop here. I interviewed every electrical contracting outfit in North Central Arkansas and not one of those electricians saw a problem with unequal ground paths.  I even interviewed the local Voc Tech instructor who trained most of them.  The prevailing question I got from practically all of them was "Why do you need two transfer switches?"  None of them knew how to do leakage tests on a live system either or what that was for.  With the exception of the work needed to be done on cutover day, I've had to do all this work myself.

Comment: Imperfect as it is, this system will give us breathing room to grow our business, if that's possible under emerging conditions.  If it is, we can go back and add more lines in a separate trench so that the dual T-lines are fully rated for 200A.  Until then, this is really the best we can do.  The choice to use 1/0 for the T-lines was a difficult one, but we were compelled to conserve resources so that we would have sufficient funds for the 30A cold room.  That cold room is on order from OnlyKem in Shanghai, China.  They use Copewell digital temperature controllers and Danfoss expansion valves.

Comment: If I don't have the cold room built by the time the equipment arrives, I might not be able to test for performance before my (30) day grace period ends.  So, much as I appreciate your input, my focus has to remain elsewhere - for now.  Even so, thank you very much for your well informed guidance.  You should really set up shop here.

Comment: Oh, and one last thing:  Could you please provide me with a diagram of what you mean exactly by "tucking the bonding jumper for the backup system into S2 instead of having it live at the generator."  I don't want to guess at your meaning here and the specific nomenclature used by power distribution electricians is a bit new to me.

Comment: @TimWhitmore -- basically, since your generator has a floating neutral, and my proposal switches the neutral, the generator side needs to provide a replacement for the neutral-ground bond at the main disconnect. It can live either inside S2, or if there's only one inlet, in the inlet instead.  (Normally, if you had a more complex system, it'd be inside the generator switchboard itself.)